# Select features by SQL statement in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, dbmanager

I want to select my features using a SQL sentence but I don't want to create a new layer out of this selection (like you would do in DB manager). Is there a way to achieve this? Some posts hint at using execute SQL process but still creates a layer out of the selection instead of just selecting the features.

Comment: What you probably want is Select by expression: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression - You have to use QGIS expressions, however, not SQL statements - even if some expressions are similar to SQL. To get help with actual expressions, add more details and show us what you want to do.

Comment: I normally tend to use SQL to query my data as I am not as good as I wish with QGIS expressions. But basically what I want is to create an expression where I can select a feature that intersects with 2 or more layers (select by location only let me do it one at a time). I will re-elaborate my question with more details

Comment: Yes, please add more details. Also have a look at `overlay_intersects` expression